# How to embed a SQLite DB (*.db file) to the AIR application?

Tags: database, actionscript-3, sqlite, air, embed

I want to emded SQLite database (*.db file) to the AIR app, like images, mp3 etc. 
This is to ensure that it was impossible to copy my database for other users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I embed a sqlite database in an Air application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573350/can-i-embed-a-sqlite-database-in-an-air-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. And even if you could package it, the data wouldn't really be protected: since an .air package is in essence nothing more than an enhanced .zip archive, anyone could just extract the database from the .air file.

What you have to do is **encrypt your database and protect it with a password** so that only authorized users can access the database.

There's ample documentation on how to do this. Here's a tutorial from Adobe to get you started: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/encrypted_database.html

Comment: You can, in fact, embed a database file in an AIR application. I've just marked this question as a dupe; this answer describes the process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573350/can-i-embed-a-sqlite-database-in-an-air-application

Comment: I should qualify my comment by saying that "embedding in the AIR application" does just mean including it in the AIR archive, which as @RIAstar says is just a .zip archive. So, it won't be protected unless you encrypt it, also as RIAstar says. But, this is much more protection than any other option AIR offers besides streaming assets at runtime over a network connection.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible. If you embed it to the air file andinstall the AIR app the db will be copied to the installation folder.

You could create the database in the user storage location

```
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("name.db");
```

Users could still navigate in explorer to the file. It will be stored under /users/username/appdata/appname/Local Store

AppData is a hidden folder.